# How to execute tests sequentially using TestNG and DataProvider

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider

I am using @dataprovider TestNG annotation to pass different set of data. My TestNG class contains @BeforeClass, @DataProvider, three @Test methods(one test using dataprovider) and @After Class. Dataprovider contains 3 sets of data(username and password)

I just want to know how I can execute the tests in the below order

--Execute the @BeforeClass

-->Go to the Test and print the first set of data from data provider
-->execute the second test case
-->execute the third test case

--Go to the Test and print the second set of data from data provider
--execute the second test case
--execute the third test case

--Go to the Test and print the third set of data from data provider
--execute the second test case
--execute the third test case

--execute the @AfterClass

---

```
public class SequentialExe {

    @BeforeClass
    public void started(){

        System.out.println("Class Started");
    }

    @DataProvider(name="testdata")
    public Object[][] getdata(){

        Object ob[] 
  []=ExcelUtils.excelread("C:/Users/Desktop/capsule.xlsx", 0);
        return ob;
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="testdata",priority=0)
    public void test01(String uname, String paswrd){

        System.out.println("Username is"+"--"+uname);
        System.out.println("Password is"+"--"+paswrd);

    }
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void test02(){

        System.out.println("This is second test case");
    }
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void test03(){

        System.out.println("This is third test case");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void end(){

        System.out.println("Class END");
    }
}
```

Now am getting the result like

---

Class Started

Username is--uname01
Password is--pwd01
Username is--uname02
Password is--pwd02
Username is--uname03
Password is--pwd03

This is second test case
This is third test case
Class END

---

I am looking  for the below result

---

Class Started

Username is--uname01
Password is--pwd01
This is second test case
This is third test case

Username is--uname02
Password is--pwd02
This is second test case
This is third test case

Username is--uname03
Password is--pwd03
This is second test case
This is third test case

Class END

---

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try parameterizing your testcase with @Factory annotation. @DataProvider works at testmethod level and @Factory works at class level. 
I tried your code with @Factory but could not produce the output expected by you.
You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output can be generated by using @Factory annotation. Reference: https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/difference-factory-dataprovider/